# How To Merge Concatenate Two PDF Files In Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, attachment, pdf, files, merge

I was wondering if there's a possibility to meet this requirement using any PDF tool (maybe Conga) in a Salesforce Org.

I'm making a LWC that must merge or conc a group of PDF files related with a Salesforce record. These documents are stored as attachments to the record and we want to append them one behind the other to create one single pdf that is the joining of the others.

I can do this without problems using an external API called Api2Pdf but the problem is that the documents has very sensitive data and we don't want to share this info sending it to the Api2Pdf external servers to be processed 
(Althought they say they comply with a privacy law the client dont want it)

Is there a way to merge this pdf attachments using some other tool like Conga? have you guys done this before? Thanks!

(link to Api2Pdf for Salesforce in github (https://github.com/Api2Pdf/api2pdf.salesforce/))

Comment: It's conceptually possible to do the processing in JavaScript, but I really don't have the bandwidth to attempt such a thing. Have you looked at a general JavaScript-based API such as [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to merge documents locally (on a client's browser side) to achieve sensitive data rules compliance.

Perhaps you can use any Javascript (ES7, ES5) library that you can include in your LWC code. For example this open-source library:
https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit

From my experience, most of such libraries respect Locker Service rules, therefore you shouldn't face with any major issues.

Cheers,
Paul